# Why does this bleak module give such an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I have trouble when I try connect a BLE esp-32 device. I'm using the template provided by the module to use it but I'm getting an error. Can you help me?

**Below is the code I use written by the module manufacturer. I plan to use it to check if the code is working or not**

```py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient
from bleak import discover
RED_LED_UUID = 'beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8'


async def run():
    devices = await discover()
    for d in devices:
        if 'Long name works now' in d.name:
            print('Found and Connecting device....')
            async with BleakClient(d.address) as client:
                print(f'Connected to {d.address}')
                val = await client.read_gatt_char(RED_LED_UUID)
                print(val)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nReceived Keyboard Interrupt')
finally:
    print('Program finished')
```

**And here is the error code that appeared when I tried to run the program**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\blemodule\test2.py", line 57, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else ADDRESS))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 650, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\blemodule\test2.py", line 26, in main
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\blemodule\venv\Lib\site-packages\bleak\__init__.py", line 433, in __aenter__
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\blemodule\venv\Lib\site-packages\bleak\__init__.py", line 471, in connect
    return await self._backend.connect(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\blemodule\venv\Lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 373, in connect
    await self.get_services()
  File "C:\Users\nguye\PycharmProjects\blemodule\venv\Lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 574, in get_services
    await asyncio.wait(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 418, in wait
    return await _wait(fs, timeout, return_when, loop)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 522, in _wait
    f.add_done_callback(_on_completion)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: '_bleak_winrt_Windows_Foundation.IAsyncOperation' object has no attribute 'add_done_callback'
```

Comment: Update the question to add the full error traceback message.

Comment: I know it but this is example code of module. How i can fix it

Comment: We can't say how to fix it, until we see your code.  I'm going to guess that you called an asyncio library function with a wrong argument.

Comment: i was update code in topic. Can u help me?

Comment: That is not enough to help.  Post the full error traceback message, as I already asked.

Comment: Please post the code as text in a code block, not as an image. Some places block imgur (the website which hosts inline images on stackoverflow) and images can't be read by screen readers. [Why should I not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Sorry, This is first use stackover. I update code and error full. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

## It's a bug

This seems to be a bug in either the Bleak or PyWinRT module. There is an open issue for PyWinRT (#14) which says that the bug first appeared with Python 3.11. The latest bleak code added a [`FutureLike` class](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/0d3fa86574cdf499ccf6ea7d4d3dc69223f82cfb/bleak/backends/winrt/client.py#L899) to wrap IAsyncOperation and uses it at lines 578-586 of the same file backends/winrt/client.py. The aforementioned class works around the pywinrt issue quoted below:

> Passing IAsyncInfo objects to methods like asyncio.wait() broke in Python 3.11 because it doesn't implement add_done_callback(). — [pywinrt issue #14](https://github.com/pywinrt/pywinrt/issues/14).

> Wraps a WinRT IAsyncOperation in a "future-like" object so that it can be passed to Python APIs. Needed until https://github.com/pywinrt/pywinrt/issues/14 — `FutureLike` docstring in backends/winrt/client.py

## How do I fix it?

You can fix it using the following in the PyCharm terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or View->Tool Windows->Terminal):

```
source venv/bin/activate
pip install git+https://github.com/hbldh/bleak@develop
```

What this does is: activates the virtual environment, then installs the latest bleak code directly from GitHub. The latest version of bleak at the time of writing this answer is 0.20.0a1. To install that exact version, change the part after the at-sign (`@`) to `0d3fa86`.

Another possible fix might be downgrading to an older version of Python, then re-installing bleak.